# Alternative to super glue

Tags: structural-engineering, materials

I have used my PCB bottom as part of my outer casing (bottom part). To do that I need to glue the PCB on my ABS (upper) casing. A special 1,5 mm line/area is used in the casing and on the outer ridge of the PCB to glue the parts. Although that works well it is a lot of work to manually apply the glue if it will go into mass production. Also, because the glue is squeezed out of a 1,5mm glue line when both parts are assembled (ABS casing and PCB) some glue will be on the outside of the casing and on the outside part of the PCB. So visually that is less appealing. The glue is also needed to make the sealing between the PCB and casing waterproof.

What can be an alternative to the glue?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Control the amount of glue administered - should be easy on a production line with syringe delivery.

Comment: @SolarMike And if it goes into mass production there should be a fixture of some kind anywaysto align things and apply the glue.

Comment: Have a look at a [router pantograph](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETgPqFHZLgY) to see if it inspires any ideas. In your case you would put the glue gun in place of the router and machine or 3D print the cam profile at twice actual size for 2:1 pantograph.

Comment: Yes indeed I think for mass produktion a modified router machine or a real glue robot might be the best solution. I was just hoping there was a magic way to close the casing without glue ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get away from gluing then there may be a few other options, but we really need more information on your requirements in order to give you a good solution.

1. ultrasonic welding, plastic parts weld very well if designed for it
2. redesign the plastic to be able to mechanically snap together, or thread together.
3. a retaining ring around the joint the bonds the two halves together, this could be solid, or a reinforced tape, or a shrink-wrap type of material.

Comment: because the PCB and the casing are both different materials ultrasonic welding will be difficult.  Yes I was also thinking about a mechanically snap, but the total hight is 5mm that will also be a challenge!

Comment: because the PCB which is 0.6 mm thick will be placed inside the abs casing (for 0.6mm) a retaining ring around the joint is not possible. But I like the idea

Comment: I added an extra picture to make it more clear

Answer (score 2):

If your parts are circular then mount them on a turntable fixture and rotate under the dispensing needle.

You should be able to find a cyanoacrylate dispensing system with solenoid control and adjustable flow rate at low cost.

Comment: no unfortunaly the parts are not circular

Answer (score 0):

You can look at PCB overmoulding if the volumes are high enough. Various companies offer this, see for example https://www.overmould.com/services/low-pressure-overmoulding/ or https://ams-tec.eu/technical-moulding/ (NB: I'm not in any way affiliated with any of them, it's just something I found on Google).

Another option would be to simply pot the PCB inside casing if you don't need to get it out again. We have used [Loctite 9492](https://www.henkel-adhesives.com/in/en/product/structural-adhesives/loctite_ea_9492.html) to pot PCBs in the past. The PCBs were coated with conformal coating beforehand. You'll have to design a potting jig for this.

Comment: overmoulding looks promising will look into that !

Answer (score 0):

RTV silicone  can be used (and is kind of the go to for electronics) but costs more than super glue (sometimes much more) and has a much longer cure time.

However, it is also thicker so can be applied in more controlled amounts, but also needs to be applied in much smaller amounts, and can be squeegeed to remove excess,

Comment: Could be an option, but I have to see if RTV is strong enough when the device falls on a hard floor. A longer cure time is even a plus because you have more time to process more steps in the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us how many you mean to produce, but one fairly common option would be to use a CNC glue dispensing machine.

I'm sure the manufacturer, or a company like loctite would be able to recommend a suitable engineering glue for this.

If you're not producing enough for that to be reasonable, consider producing some kind of jig to ease hand application. Also, there are special foot peddle air-actuated glue dispensers which may be much easier to use accurately than a tube of super glue.

A more budget friendly approach is to buy a 3d printer and modify it to hold a glue dispensing tool.

In all of these cases you will want to call a few big glue manufacturers and describe your application, and have them recommend a glue.